# HBase integration with Hadoop - sync support

Tags: hadoop, hbase, synchronization

I am relatively new to HBase or Hadoop and this may sound naive. However..

I have issues in the integration of Hbase with the exisitng hadoop cluster.
For the purpose of learning, i configured a 2 nodes Hadoop 1.1.1 cluster. Lets say master and slave.
I could even run the map reduce examples without any problems.

On Master --- 1. Namenode 2. Secondary Namenode 3. Job Tracker +  4. Datanode 5. Task tracker

On Salve  --- 1. Datanode 2. Task Tracker

Now, i want to run HBase 0.90.6 on top of this hadoop cluster. The problem is that this version of HBase is bundled with Hadoop-code-append jar. Now to integrate HBase 0.90.6 with Hadoop 1.1.1, i have replaced the hadoop core jar in hbase lib directory with the hadoop-core-1.1.1 jar. I also have to place the commons-configuration jar under the hbase lib folder. Then make HBase point to the hadoop cluster via hbase.rootdir property under hbase-site.xml This works perfectly fine.

The problem occurs when i start the HBase master web UI and it says

"You are currently running the HMaster without HDFS append support enabled. This may result in data loss. Please see the HBase wiki for details."

When i searched for the sync support, it looks like not all versions of Hadoop support this.

Now the question is, How to get the sync support with Hbase 0.90.6 and hadoop 1.1.1 combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you turned on append support on both `hbase-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`? This works for HBase 0.96.0.

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.support.append</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

You will have to restart the cluster after making this change.